# Simulink: how to store a local variable in level 2 S-function?

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I'm starting from msfuntmpl_basic.m and modifying it to output audio from an audio device.

Where can I store the device (dsp.AudioRecorder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be use the 'persistent' attribute for the variable in a function.

Comment: Why not use the "from audio device" block directly as a block in your model? That may be faster.

Comment: There is no "from audio device" block in 2016a.  There is an "Audio Device Reader" block but it gives me a portAudio error msg when I try to use it.